# Rspec describe NameError uninitialized constant scope

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm getting NameError uninitialized constant like below:

```
Failures:

  1) Direction turn right faced south rotates to west
     Failure/Error: expect(Move.right(Direction::South)).to eq(Direction::West)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Move
     # ./spec/unit_tests/direction_spec.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Direction turn right faced west rotates to north
     Failure/Error: expect(Move.right(Direction::West)).to eq(Direction::North)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Move
     # ./spec/unit_tests/direction_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Direction turn right faced north rotates to east
     Failure/Error: expect(Move.right(Direction::North)).to eq(Direction::East)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Move
     # ./spec/unit_tests/direction_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Direction turn right faced east rotates to south
     Failure/Error: expect(Move.right(Direction::East)).to eq(Direction::South)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Move
     # ./spec/unit_tests/direction_spec.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02345 seconds
14 examples, 4 failures
```

This is the code I have:

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
require 'direction'

describe Direction do

    subject(:Move) { Direction::Move.new }

    describe 'turn right' do
        context 'faced south' do
            it 'rotates to west' do
                expect(Move.right(Direction::South)).to eq(Direction::West)
            end
        end
        context 'faced west' do
            it 'rotates to north' do
                expect(Move.right(Direction::West)).to eq(Direction::North)
            end
        end
        context 'faced north' do
            it 'rotates to east' do
                expect(Move.right(Direction::North)).to eq(Direction::East)
            end
        end
        context 'faced east' do
            it 'rotates to south' do
                expect(Move.right(Direction::East)).to eq(Direction::South)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Is there a reason why subject is not working? I've also tried `let` but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use subject name in lower case

```
subject(:move) { Direction::Move.new }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Move` to be interpreted as a method call, you need to add either a receiver or an argument list. I.e. you need to use either

```
expect(self.Move.right(Direction::South)).to eq(Direction::West)
```

or

```
expect(Move().right(Direction::South)).to eq(Direction::West)
```

Otherwise it will be interpreted as dereferencing a constant.